# In SQL Server, how can I test the instance I'm currently connecting is default or not?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, instance

In SQL Server, how can I test the instance I'm currently connecting is default or not? I mean how can I using **TSQL** to get this information?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Select @@Servername` or `Select ServerProperty('instancename')`

ServerProperty will display NULL if you are on the default instance.

See [@@ServerName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933172(v=SQL.80).aspx) and [ServerProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259183(v=SQL.80).aspx) for further information

Answer (score 0):

Well you should already know this to be honest by the connection string you are using...

Using 2005 Connection strings you would see;

Standard connection string;

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

Instance connection string;

```
Server=myServerName\theInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```